# how to display taxonomies in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I have created some Taxonomies for posts. I use the following code to display. but it doesn't display anything. What is wrong with this code?

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'link', array("fields" => "all"));

$link = $term_list[0]->name ;
```

Comment: Try adding `global $post;` above call to `wp_get_post_terms`. Better show us more of your code.

Comment: This is the right code. I didn't enter values at backend.